# How to use requests in Python 3 to fetch data from website that utilizes JavaScript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests, client-side

I have been playing around with the requests library in Python 3 for quite some time now, and have decided to create a test program. For this program, I'm using the website https://ytmp3.cc/ as an example. But it turns out that a lot is going on, on the client-side it seems.

Some keys and other stuff are being generated, and I have been using Firefox's built-in network monitor, to figure out in which requests this is being made, but without luck.

As far as I know, the requests-library can't keep a "page" open and modify the DOM and content, by making more requests.

Anyone whom could take a look, and give a qualified guess on how the special keys are generated, and how I could possibly get these for my own requests.

Fx when loading the webpage, the first request made is for the root, and the response contains the webpage HTML. What I noticed is that at the bottom, there's an url containing some key and number.

```
<script id="cs" src="js/converter-1.0.js?o=7_1a-a&=_1519520467"></script>
id      7_1a-a
number  _1519520467`
```

This is used for making the next request, but then a lot of following requests are being made, and some other keys are made as well. But I can't find where these come from since they are not returned by a request.

I know that when inserting a Youtube link, a request will be made to an url, as seen below.

`https://d.ymcdn.cc/check.php?callback=jQuery33107639361236859977_1519520481166&v=eVD9j36Ke94&f=mp3&k=7_1a-a&_=1519520481168`

This returns the following:

`jQuery33107639361236859977_1519520481166({"sid":"21","hash":"2a6b2475b059101480f7f16f2dde67ac","title":"M\u00d8 - Kamikaze (Official Video)","ce":1,"error":""})`

From this I can construct the download url, using the hash from above:

`https://yyd.ymcdn.cc/ + 2a6b2475b059101480f7f16f2dde67ac (hash) + /eVD9j36Ke94` (youtube video id)

But how do I get

`jQuery33107639361236859977_1519520481166&v=eVD9j36Ke94`    and    `1519520481168`

Which I need to create the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably save yourself and the operator of that website a lot of headache by just using [`youtube-dl`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl), specifically with the `--extract-audio --audio-format mp3` options. It's probably what that website itself uses.

`youtube-dl` is written in Python and can [easily be used programatically](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl).

If you insist on sending requests to that website for whatever reason, here's how I'd do it:

- `callback=jQuery33107639361236859977_1519520481166` specifies the name of the callback for the JSONP request. Any name you provide will be printed back out. For example, passing `callback=foo` will result in the following response:

  ```
  foo({...})
  ```

  You can omit it entirely and the server will serve just a JSON response in this case, which is nice.
- `_=1519520481168` is just to prevent the response being cached. It's randomly generated, just like the above parameter. The website checks for existence, however, so you have to at least pass something in.
- The website, like many, checks for a valid `Referer` header.

Here's a minimal cURL command line to make a request to that website:

```
curl 'https://d.ymcdn.cc/check.php?v=eVD9j36Ke94&f=mp3&k=aZa4__&_=1' -H 'Referer: https://ytmp3.cc/'
```

Comment: So that the callback, is to store the response JSON? Gives sense.
But what about the ID _=15....? How can this ID prevent caching?

And also I see that in the request url, you use &k=aZa4__
How can it be that you can keep reusing this? I thought it was specific for each request?

Comment: @user6827994: JSON is valid JavaScript but can't often be used cross-domain because of security restrictions. JSONP is the name given to the technique where you wrap JSON in a function call so that it can be loaded cross-domain with only a `<script>` tag. As for `_= 1519520481168`, you can just as easily use `oifjpoaisdapsdk=aiosjdoiasjd`. The only thing that matters is that the URL changes each time, since browsers will always treat it as a new resource.

Comment: @user6827994: As for the `k=aZa4__`, I don't know what it does. All that the website checks for is that it's a string six characters long consisting of letters from `{'a', '_', '-', '7', '1', '4', 'Z'}`. If you want to mimic a browser and generate exactly the same URL format as the JavaScript does, it's not difficult. ` 1519520481168` is just a UNIX timestamp that you can generate with `int(time.time() * 1000)`.